# Ubuntu - Sounds from both headphones and speakers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, speakers

Both the speakers and the headphones keep playing the sound with headphone plugged in.

Comment: I have voted to migrate this to super-user. Just so you know, I have the same issue and would be interested to see an answer.

Comment: Funny, I am looking for how to do the reverse. As you probably know a sound goes not only via an ears, but also via a bones, and so on, so it probably would be an interesting experience to hear a music that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. Run 'alsamixer' in the terminal and try out the volume levels for speaker / headphones / master. Hope it helps others.

Comment: there is actually a setting in the sound preferences to mute the speakers when headphones are plugged in. but im glad you found a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Seek out either "headphone jack sence" or "auto-mute" item in alsamixer and use up/down keys to enable it.